# Why am I getting 'No directive found with exportAs ngModel' error when using FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-ngmodel

This is my code and I get "No directive found with exportAs 'ngModel'." error message. I've tried adding FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule to my app.module.ts (declarations) but still have this issue.

Version: angular 15.2.9

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Course name</label>
        <input ngModel name="name" required minlength="3" #name="ngModel" type="text" id="name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">Course category</label>
        <select name="" id="category" class="form-control">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option *ngFor="let categoryName of categories" [value]="categoryName.id">{{ categoryName.name }}</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label for="moneyBack">
                <input type="checkbox" id="moneyBack">
                money back he
            </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">make</button>
</form>
```

```
My component.ts file:
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
})
export class FormComponent {
  @Input('name') name : any;
categories = [
  { id: 1, name: 'dev'},
  { id: 2, name: 'dev2'},
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what approach you're trying to use with the form.
But the issue is with your first input

```
<input ngModel name="name" required minlength="3" #name="ngModel" type="text" id="name" class="form-control">
```

Basically you're missusing "ngModel".
So I would suggest to change it to this

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="name" name="name" required minlength="3" type="text" id="name" class="form-control">
```

Comment: i'm still getting an error message: "Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' ". In the .ts file i have an input field aliased as "name", but still doesn't work.

Comment: Please share the component file (.ts)

Comment: Added the component file @Dexmente

Comment: I recreated a brand new app with your code, got your same error, and it dissappeared by just removing `#name="ngModel"` .
But I see on your .ts file a `@Input('name') name : any;`, this is called a decorator, and this in particular, is to receive data from a parent component, not to handle form inputs. So that's probably it. Just declare a variable called name to handle it in the template. That should be it.